# How to make PHP header location redirect use PHP generated URL

Tags: php

This is fairly simple but I cant work it out.

I'm building a wordpress site, and I want a redirect on my 404 page using PHP instead of javascript.

```
<?php header("Location: www.myblogurl.com"); ?>
```

And I use this in my wordrpess websites to get the URL of my blog...

```
<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>
```

But I can't seem to merge the two PHP scripts together, please see my poor attempt below.

```
<?php

    $location = bloginfo('url');

    header( 'Location:' + $location ) ;

?>
```

This seems to echo my website URL instead of redirecting.

Can any help me please, thanks.

Comment: `.` is the concatenate operator in PHP not `+`

Comment: Thank you all for your responses

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) in wordpress echo's the information instead of returning it. You should use [`get_bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo).

The docs says:

> This always prints a result to the browser. If you need the values for use in PHP, use [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo).

A sample would be:

```
<?php
header('Location: ' . get_bloginfo('url'));
?>
```

---

You are using the `+` to concatenate 2 strings. This is wrong in PHP the `+` is a math operator for things like `$result = 1 + 1`. You need to use the [`.`](http://php.net/language.operators.string) operator: `$text = 'hello' . 'world'`.

Comment: Thank you for help and better script :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well first correct + with .

String concatenation works in php with .

```
 <?php

$location = bloginfo('url');

header( 'Location: ' . $location ) ;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use **get_bloginfo()** instead of **bloginfo()** and replace the **+** with **.**

Comment: +1 because you are the only one (besides me) who posted the real solution instead of the `+` operator (which is a side problem)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<?php

    $location = bloginfo('url');

    header( 'Location:' . $location ) ;

?>
```

You were using Javascript syntax for concatenation in PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $location = bloginfo('url');

    header( 'Location:'.$location ) ;

?>
```

This should be your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dot (.)` not a `plus (+)`.

```
header( 'Location:' . $location ) ;
```